# Sending informations from iOS to OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, ios4

I am looking at sending informations from the iPhone/iPad to the Mac. A simple case would be moving a slider on the iPad and returning the value ( say, between 1 and 100 ) to the Mac ( terminal for example ) in any case I assume I'd have to go with wifi or Bluetooth .

Would anybody be able to point me towards which libraries and frameworks I should look at ? Would GameKit accomodate such thing ? Bonjour maybe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bonjour could be used to find the service which I would recommend using and I would use something like an AsyncSocket to establish a connection and send data between them. GameKit would not help you at this time as it is not available on the Mac.

Another option would be to use Bojour to find the service and an NSURLRequest to send/receive data to it, depending on how much and how fast you want to send stuff.